# Position of text box

Tags: c#, textbox, position

I want to make a game that you write the word you want your friend to guess here **Form2**:

[image]

Then **Form3** will show up

[image]

My problem is when I click **button A** i want one or some textbox show up dynamically in the **right position**.
For example my word from **Form2** is **BANANA** when i click A button it should show up like this   A A A
I use a fuction in Form2 like this

```
public  void FindString(char Someword )
{

     int i = textBox1.TextLength;
     for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
     {
        if ( Someword == textBox1.Text[j])
        {
                       //what to do here

        }
    }
}
```

Then I can use a values of `j` to determine the position of the word in `Form3` (can't deal with multi position like the example).

Comment: Can you publish the full source code here ?

Answer (score 1):

For each time the char at j matches you append the char to a string. for each mismatch append a blank. After loading up the string you can clear and update the textbox.  If you want it to be able to handle inputs with phrases from 'form2' then you can check for blanks before sending it to the textbox.

```
        List<char> guessWord = new List<char>(25);
        int i = textBox1.TextLength;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (input == passWord[j])
            {
                guessWord.Insert(j, passWord[j]); //set j index of an array or list to the corresponding character
            }
            else
            {
                guessWord.Insert(j,' ');  // or you can use an underscore _ to indicate that there should have been a letter there.  You could also add a line here to create a list or array containing wrong guesses and display those
            }
        }
        label1.Text = ""; //clear prior guesses

        foreach(char c in guessWord)
        {
            label1.Text += c;
        }
```

Of course this depends on how you are displaying your text.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
//New list to store pressed chars
List<char> usedChars = new List<char>();

public void FindString (char Somechar)
{
     //New StringBuilder to build final string
     StringBuilder sbWordIs = new StringBuilder();

     int i = textBox1.TextLength;
     for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
     {
        if (Somechar == textBox1.Text[j])
        {
            //Store new correct char
            if (!usedChars.Contains(Somechar)) usedChars.Add (Somechar);
        }

        //Check whether each char in word was already pressed or not
        if (usedChars.Contains(textBox1.Text[j])) sbWordIs.Append(textBox1.Text[j]);
        else sbWordIs.Append ("_"); //If not, show an underscore
    }

    //Say yor new textbox is named "textBox2"
    textBox2.Text = sbWordIs.ToString();
}
```

(Untested)

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<char>     guessWord = new List<char>(25);
        int i = textBox1.TextLength;
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        if (input == passWord[j])
        {
            guessWord.Insert(j, passWord[j]); //set j index of an array or     list to the corresponding character
        }
            else
    {
            guessWord.Insert(j,' ');  // or you can use an underscore _ to indicate that there should have been a letter there.  You could also add a line here to create a list or array containing wrong guesses and display those
        }
    }
        label1.Text = ""; //clear prior guesses

        foreach(char c in guessWord)
    {
        label1.Text += c;
    }
```